# SQL Column + DataType concatenation in select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

So I think I know the answer to this but I would like to check with some other professionals. We have a statement that is part of an insert statement that looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO <Table_Name> 
SELECT   CHAR(34) + RTRIM(Col_1) + CHAR(34)
        ,CHAR(34) + RTRIM(Col_2) + CHAR(34)
        ,CHAR(34) + RTRIM(Col_3) + CHAR(34)
        ,CHAR(34) + RTRIM(Col_4) + CHAR(34)
```

To me this is adding character padding to the selected columns. Am I correct in this way of thinking or is there something more that I missed? Thank you for your consideration.

Regards,
Z

Comment: It's adding quotes, why would you want to do that?

Comment: It's just surrounding it with double quotes

Comment: Try asking someone where you are why they are adding double quotes, there may be a good reason for doing that.

Comment: Your explanations make sense as the full script make a CSV text file and the columns and subsequent data in the columns have quotes around them. As to why it was write this way I don't know. I have inherited a system that seems to have been built on a solid foundation but has a million little pieces of code/scripts duct taped to it and I am just trying to sort it all out.

Comment: Also how do i give you all credit for answering my question.

Comment: You can only give credit to an actual answer, but you can 'upvote' helpful comments. Users won't notice that in most cases though :P